# Regression of two data data sets of the same experiment

Tags: regression, python, statsmodels

I have two data sets collected by different methods about the same phenomena, one 'bare' and other where I believe there is a constant value added (the same phenomena, with the data collected by a different method, plus a constant percentage value added to each data point). I´m trying to calculate

1. Check if the two data sets are really representing the same phenomena and
2. The constant percentage difference.

I made two linear regressions with statsmodels on each data set and can see that the regression lines are parallel. I was thinking on

1. Calculate the correlation of the two data sets to answer 1 - seems to be ok
2. Subtracting the difference between the two regression lines to evaluate the percentage difference, but it seems to be incorrect to do so.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Parallel regression lines would suggest that a constant had been added to the values, rather than a constant *percentage* applied (which would be understood as *multiplying* each value $y$ by a constant $1 + \delta/100$, where $\delta$ is the percentage). Could you clarify which of these operations you mean? And exactly what "linear regressions" are you performing? Is there another variable involved?

Comment: I´m doing a linear regression with only one dependent variable. Having the same phenomena and two different ways of gathering the data, I agree that I have two sets of variables. There is no other variable involved.

Comment: If you gather the data in two different ways, then you have *two* variables, not one (or, if you like, two distinct measurements of the same "variable"--but those measurements must be managed and analyzed as two separate variables).  But is there *some other variable* involved in your regressions or are you regressing these variables against each other?

Comment: I have the same independent variable for both experiments, I´m not regressing the two dependent variables against each other.

Comment: Thanks again, @whuber, you clarified a conceptual problem. It is indeed a $1+\delta/100$ thing, not a constant value, so indeed the two regression lines should not be parallel. The comparison and finding the $\delta$ value problems stand.

Answer (score 1):

Gregory Chow developed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test to statistically compare two regression equations. If the scale of the dependent variable is different then you might consider normalizing the Y values before the analysis. Another approach is to study each data set for a model that might include lags and/or deterministic structure and perhaps a power trasndormation. Careful analysis/review of the two models might suggest the nature of the differences, if any.